# Generic type bounded by another generic

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

Suppose I have this:

```
interface Shape {}
interface Square extends Shape {}
interface Circle extends Shape {}

interface ShapeBuilder<S extends Shape> {}
```

I want something like this:

```
class ShapeBuilderFactory<SB extends ShapeBuilder> {
    SB<Square> getSquareBuilder(){...}
    SB<Circle> getCircleBuilder(){...}
}
```

This code doesn't compile (because ShapeBuilder is a raw type), but I hope you understand the idea.
Is it possible to do something like this in java? How?

(the real problem isn't with shapes builders and factories, I used this example for simplicity)

**Edit** (more context)

I have different kind of builders:

```
interface RegularShapeBuilder<S extends Shape> extends ShapeBuilder<S> {}
interface FunnyShapeBuilder<S extends Shape> extends ShapeBuilder<S> {}

class RegularSquareBuilder extends RegularShapeBuilder<Square> {}
class FunnySquareBuilder extends FunnyShapeBuilder<Square> {}
class RegularCircleBuilder extends RegularShapeBuilder<Circle> {}
class FunnyCircleBuilder extends FunnyShapeBuilder<Circle> {}
```

And I want the factory to do things like this:

```
ShapeBuilderFactory<FunnyShapeBuilder> funnyShapeBuilderFactory = ...;
FunnyShapeBuilder<Square> funnySquareBuilder = funnyShapeBuilderFactory.getSquareBuilder();
```

Comment: What are you trying to acheive by making ShapeBuilderFactory generic?  Obviously a ShapeBuilder cant produce both a square and a circle, because you said it can only produce one type.

Comment: I am trying to make the factory class able to return different kinds of builders (regularBuilder, funnyBuilder, etc). I want to have a regularShapeBuilderFactory and a funnyShapeBuilderFactory as instances of the same class.

Comment: Ok, but why do they need to expose the type of builder they use?  Do the different kinds of builders do other things that you would need the sub-type for?

Comment: Yes, the different kind of builders have different methods (maybe using builders in the example wasnt the best choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just have:

```
class ShapeBuilderFactory {
    ShapeBuilder<Square> getSquareBuilder(){...}
    ShapeBuilder<Circle> getCircleBuilder(){...}
}
```

**Edit**

So if you really must have the ShapeBuilder subtype in your factory, you'll need to declare each one of them:

```
class ShapeBuilderFactory<SqB extends ShapeBuilder<Square>, 
                          CiB extends ShapeBuilder<Circle>> {
    SqB getSquareBuilder(){...}
    CiB getCircleBuilder(){...}
}
```

So you'll have to declare that as:

```
ShapeBuilderFactory<FunnySquareBuilder, FunnyCircleBuilder> funnyShapeBuilder = ...
```

But you will be able to say

```
FunnyShapeBuilder<Square> funnySquareBuilder = funnyShapeBuilderFactory.getSquareBuilder();
```

The problem you've got is that an implementation of ShapeBuilder can only create one type of shape.  That's how you've declared it.

If this were my code I would use the `ShapeBuilderFactory` definition I initially wrote and instantiate it with funny or regular builders.  Isn't the point of having these interfaces actually using them?

Comment: because each method of the factory returns a different generic builder

Comment: Sorry, I formatted it badly so the <Square> and <Circle> got swallowed

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the real code is more complex and have nothing in common with builders, I wanted to know if Java has any trick to solve this, but it looks like it hasnt.
Anyway, I like your solution more than mine (I made several factory classes).
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
class ShapeBuilderFactory<S extends Shape, SB extends ShapeBuilder<S>> {
```

Although you might consider whether you need it to be generic at all.

Comment: I dont want the factory to work with only one kind of shape, the builder passed to the factory should be generic

Answer (score 0):

Drop the generics on the factory class, do something like :

```
interface Shape {}
interface Square extends Shape {}
interface Circle extends Shape {}

interface ShapeBuilder<S extends Shape> {}

class ShapeBuilderFactory {
    ShapeBuilder<Square> getSquareBuilder(){...}
    ShapeBuilder<Circle> getCircleBuilder(){...}
}
```